# Expanding / grow a JQuery element selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the Jquery example below, I would like to expand $(this) before it is cloned, so it includes everything contained in the parent class "comment". How do I do this? I've tried using ReplaceWith($(this).parent('.comment').clone()... and it does not work!

```
$(document).ready(

function(){ 

$('.forumthreadtitle').siblings().hide(); 
$('.forumthreadtitle').click( function() {
$('#first-post').replaceWith($(this).clone().attr('id','first-post'));

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the closest `class="comment"` parent and clone it, do this:

```
$(this).closest(".comment").clone();
```

`.parent(selector)` only finds if it's the **immediate** parent.  The equivalent for this (since comment isn't the element itself) would be: `.parents(".comment:first")`.

Comment: I would like clone everything below the comment class - all of comment's children - not just comment. Do I have to change this code at all to do so? In my testing of this code the parent's children are not being reproduced in the clone...